# Python source code What is the point of using for(;;) instead of while?

Tags: c, cpython

I love python and want to contribute. I came across this line in the cpython source code.

```
for (;;) {
    item = iternext(it);
    if (item == NULL)
        break;
    cmp = PyObject_IsTrue(item);
    Py_DECREF(item);
    if (cmp < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(it);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (cmp > 0) {
        Py_DECREF(it);
        Py_RETURN_TRUE;
    }
}
```

What's the point of using `for(;;)` and

```
if (item == NULL)
        break;
```

instead of `while(item!=NULL)` is it because the programmer wants `iternext(it)` to be executed at least once? This doesn't seem very intuitive to me but since its python source code I believe there must be a good reason?

Comment: that, and the fact that if `item` is `NULL`, `cmp = PyObject_IsTrue(item);` and the rest shouldn't execute.

Comment: You could write for(;item = iternext(it);) { (or while (item = iternext(it)) too :-) but some (likely also guido van rossum) find this kind of construction confusing as it's a condition check that does an assignment as a side effect.  Python itself disallows while loops that work this way.

Comment: there's no need for a condition up there. You'll find out that `while` with a condition often calls for a second identical test in the `while` loop...

Comment: related: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124176/whats-the-term-for-whiletrue-loop-with-break-inside/124191#124191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a loop that is exited in the middle. To make it a while loop that behaves identically, you would have to write

```
item = iternext(it);
while (item != NULL) {
    cmp = PyObject_IsTrue(item);
    Py_DECREF(item);
    if (cmp < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(it);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (cmp > 0) {
        Py_DECREF(it);
        Py_RETURN_TRUE;
    }
    item = iternext(it);
}
```

but that means duplicating one line; it also places the second `iternext` far away from the while statement, thus making the connection less obvious.

Comment: Mind you, `while ((item = iternext(it)) != NULL) {` could be used to avoid duplication, and it's perfectly idiomatic C code for this sort of scenario. It's possible they dislike assignments in conditional tests though (Python itself doesn't allow it at all), though I don't see any explicit guidelines in [PEP7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/) related to this.